# Sitecom router AC-1200 (X7) keeps disconnecting my wireless

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My Sitecom wireless router keeps disconnecting. Cabled internet is perfect, but wireless is flaky.

It's very fast, up until a few seconds into the connection (speedtest, Youtube stream, download, browsing, etc...) then it disconnects. No data is send through anymore. I can restart the speedtest and it happens again: very stable and fast first few seconds (around 6 to 10) and then, nothing anymore.

This happens will all my devices that I connect to it. (iPad, iPhone, Dell Laptop, MacBook pro)

Any idea what's going on and how to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the setting 'Hardware Accelerator'. Disabling this resulted in a 100% stable signal.

[image]